# Nested table height auto increase?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I am trying to create a report in SSRS using Report Builder 3.0 where there is an ungrouped section of data (in the screenshot this is called "Risks") followed by a grouped section of data "Controls". There can be many controls to one risk row as seen in the row with the "Ref" 3a. After the grouped set of controls it goes back to the ungrouped risk info (see below).

#### screenshot

[image: Link to screenshot of report]

I have made this work by using a nested table inside one of the cells, this all looked fine until I added a larger amount of data in the cell "Consequences". As you can see this does not look good at the moment as the inner table does not grow.

My question, is there a way to make the inner table grow, so the 2nd row text would be in the middle of that row and the background colour would take up the whole row, so it does not leave a white space?

I really appreciate any help you can give.

Thanks,
Glenn

Comment: Does the consequences come from the same data scource? I.e. can you run a quer agaist both and pull out the risk data agaist each consequence?

Comment: This is an old question and if you have your own work around I'm really interest. You can post your own answer.

Comment: Hi, Sorry not solved as it is not possible. All data is from one query however a risk can have many controls and this information reported in the middle of the table (clients requirement). Unfortunately you get the effect in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe this to be possible as the nested tablix is by its **own** right optimised for space and visual appearance.

I know what you want to do and I can only suggest you tweak yourn report to query this data in **one** and produce one tablix. Not ideal I know as this will mess the arrangement.

Comment: Accepted this as an answer as it is not possible.
Thanks.